# Mapped memory and SSE

Tags: assembly, intel, sse, memory-mapping

I found this paragraph in the Intel developer manual:

> From the chaper "PROGRAMMING WITH SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4 AND AESNI"
>
> Streaming loads must not be used to reference memory addresses that
>   are mapped to I/O devices having side effects or when reads to these
>   devices are destructive. This is because MOVNTDQA is speculative in
>   nature.

Anyone could clarify this question?

I'm asking because I'm thinking to apply some SSE assembly to OpenGL [mapped buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping), but I fear about that *destructive* word. Is this subject applied to mapped memory? Actually I don't know what's behind a glMapBuffer call.

I don't think my graphic card will be destroyed (:), but surely that word doesn't sound good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Destructive here would refer to reads that can only be done once, such as when a device presents a memory-mapped way to read the next item from its queue. In that case, reading from that location a second time would give a second result. This is bad because MOVNTDQA is speculative, so the fetch may be performed even if the instruction is ultimately skipped due to a mis-predicted branch. The data from the first fetch would be irretrievably destroyed, though with no actual harm to the hardware.

Since you're only trying to access ordinary RAM on a different device, and not a MMIO register, you don't need to worry.